# How to stop shell command injection in spring

Tags: spring, shell, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, qualys

We have got few security holes reported in our Qualys report which says that commands can be injected using a url as below.

```
/adc/Acc?sort=popular%26q=%3Apopular%3Aall%3A~WATCHES%26show=ping%20-c2%20-i91%20localhost
```

Here the security team was successfully able to inject ping command but they say that they could have injected a more harmful command as easily.

I can add a xss filter pattern to remove any word with 'ping' in it but that would not stop other commands from running and customers will not be able to use a search word containing 'ping'.

Is there a cleaner and recommended approach to fix this in spring?

Comment: Why would that URL make your service execute shell commands? Is that something you set up specifically or why does that even happen?

Comment: You need to show your code